# How to remove borders from <audio> tag?

Tags: css

I want to remove the orange border from the audio tag.

[image: audiotag]

I've tried using CSS, but it didn't work:

```css
    &::-webkit-media-controls-panel {
      background: #F4F8FE;
      &:focus {
        border: none;
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to set the `audio`:s outline to `none`

```
audio {
  &:focus {
    outline: none;
  }
}
```

Hovewer, it's not recommended to remove focus outline due to accessibility:
https://www.a11yproject.com/posts/2013-01-25-never-remove-css-outlines/